# Is it possible to replace an Intel Atom D425 processor?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, cpu, desktop-computer

I have a PC with Intel atom D425 processor, does it is possible to swap it with another without replacing the motherboard?

Full PC specs:

- Intel Atom D425 single-core 1.80 GHz,
- 2 GB DDR2 RAM (it came with 1 GB, but I have increased),
- Power supply 400 watts,
- GPU integrated Intel,
- Hard Disk 500GB,
- Motherboard model is unknown (because I didn't built this PC),
- OS Windows 10 32bit.

Comment: Knowing the motherboard model is crucial to answer this question. Fortunately this info can often be acquired by using a system utility like CPU-Z or something alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The processor is soldered to your motherboard and cannot be replaced.

According to [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/49489/intel-atom-processor-d425-512k-cache-1-80-ghz.html) the "socket" is FCBGA559 which means

- FC = [Flip chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_chip)
- BGA = [Ball grid array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) - soldered
- 559 = 559 pins/pads

You cannot replace your processor without buying a new motherboard.